# Can I replace disk containing /home without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I have formatted my hard disks so that /home sits in one separate disk. Now that disk has become faulty. I am wondering whether it is possible to replace only that disk and make a new /home partion on a new disk, so that I can avoid a complete reinstall of the OS? (I know that almost all my user data will be lost)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is yes, you don't need to re-install OS. You can create a new partition (block device like /dev/sdb2) and use it for /home. **You can also copy the data in old /home over if you have a good backup or the old home is still readable.**

In your case, it seems that the old /home (disk) became faulty. You want to use a new partition or new disk for /home. It is fine and you don't need to re-install the OS.

Steps in brief (recommend doing this using a LIVE CD, you don't HAVE TO though):

1. create partition for `/home`
2. create file system (e.g. ext4) => `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb2`
3. mount it as `/home` => for example => `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb2 /home`
4. mount your old home if it is still mountable, e.g. `mount -t fs_type /dev/sdaX /mnt/old_home` otherwise you'll have to restore data from a good backup
5. Use rsync to copy data, e.g. from a backup mounted as /backup/home `rsync -axHAX --progress --verbose /backup/home/ /home`
6. Remember to edit your `/etc/fstab` and update the block device/FS for new `/home`

Reboot and you should be good to go;-)

Comment: You might want to run the `rsync` command with `sudo` to preserve ownership information too.