# Moved /home to a separate partition, now I can't log into it

Tags: partitioning, permissions, home-directory

I looked at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) and [that](http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/separatehome) then attempted to move /home to a (pre-existing) partition. Now I am unable to log into it.

I tried to use `chown` in recovery mode as per the psychocats tutorial, only to be told that /home/*username* doesn't exist. But when I run 'locate *username*', it's the first directory listed.

What did I miss?

Comment: paste the output of `mount` or `findmnt`. You should probably look into the answer here and review what you have done: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217397/can-i-replace-disk-containing-home-without-reinstalling-ubuntu/217415#217415

Comment: The partition wasn't mounting. I hadn't created a user directory, I had just dumped everything into /home

Comment: `locate` consults a database that is only rebuilt once in a while, so it can be out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run ubuntu on normal mode, after press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> and then login with your user name and password, now write `sudo chmod 777 -R /home/Your_user_folder`

If not posible, put the terminal answer here.

Comment: If `chown` does not work, I doubt that this will...

Comment: I hadn't created the user_folder, I had just copied everything to /home. `mkdir` and `mv` have sorted everything, thank you. Well, almost everything, I still have to figure out how to get my configs for Cinnamon and Firefox back

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the fstab file system table is still pointing at your old home partition or directory. Can you print or output the contents of `/etc/fstab`

You will likely need to change the entry for mounting `/home`

Comment: Thanks. `fstab` was okay, I just needed the user directory in /home.